# MPI_Bcast segmentation fault

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am broadcasting a pointer to an array

```
MPI_Bcast(&xd_sim_send, Nooflines_Sim, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

from process 0 and receiving this broadcast from processes other than 0

```
MPI_Bcast(&xd_sim_recv, Nooflines_Sim, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I get segmentation fault 11 when I try to read the received value.
Like this

```
for(i=0; i<Numlines_Sim; i++)
printf("%f\n",xd_sim_recv[i]);fflush(stdout);
```

What is wrong here, Could you please help me fix it?

Comment: How are you allocating the variable `xd_sim_recv` in the processes other than root?

Comment: float *xd_sim_send, *xd_sim_recv;
xd_sim_send = (float *)calloc( Nooflines_Sim, sizeof(float) );
xd_sim_recv = (float *)calloc( Numlines_Sim, sizeof(float));

Comment: Sorry typo, i meant xd_sim_recv

Comment: You don't need to give the address of the vectors, because those variables are already pointers. Just give them without `&`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to receive the data in a vector other than the one used by root process, then you should do something like this (pseudocode):

```
if (THIS PROCESS IS ROOT) {
    MPI_Bcast(xd_sim_send, Nooflines_Sim, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else {
    MPI_Bcast(xd_sim_recv, Numlines_Sim, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

without the `&`, because the variables `xd_sim_send` `xd_sim_recv` are already pointers, that is what `MPI_Bcast` needs.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make sence to send a pointer, since that pointer will be invalid in the other parallel process, send the buffer instead:

```
MPI_Bcast(xd_sim_send, Nooflines_Sim, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Not to mention that even if by some extraordinary stroke of luck the pointer is valid, you never actually sent the data that it was pointing to.

Comment: Show us how you use MPI_Recv.

Comment: MPI_Bcast(xd_sim_recv, Nooflines_Sim, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

Comment: Is Numlines_Sim greater or equal to Nooflines_Sim?

Comment: both have same values onl name is different in root and other than root processes.